# Can't run dev web site using python manage.py

Tags: django

I can't run app using command line. After add more configuration on settings.py file

```
python manage.py runserver
usage: manage.py [-h] [--config-dir DIR] [--config-file PATH] [--version]
manage.py: error: unrecognized arguments: runserver
```

This is 
configloader.py

```
from oslo_config import cfg
# from oslo.config import cfg

rabbitmq_opt_group = cfg.OptGroup(name='rabbitmq', title='Configuration for rabbitmq')

rabbitmq_opts = [
    cfg.StrOpt('server_ip', default='127.0.0.1', help='ip of rabbitmq server'),
    cfg.IntOpt('server_port', default=5672, help='port of rabbitmq server'),
    cfg.FloatOpt('retry_time', default=0.2, help='interval for retry connect to server'),
    cfg.FloatOpt('interval_increase', default=0.2, help='increase unit after connect to server fail'),
    cfg.IntOpt('max_increase', default=10, help='Max sleep time when try to connect to server'),
    cfg.StrOpt('username', default='guest', help='username of account to connect rabbitmq server'),
    cfg.StrOpt('password', default='guest', help='password of account to connect rabbitmq server'),
]

worker_opt_group = cfg.OptGroup(name='worker', title='Configuration of worker')

worker_opts = [
    cfg.IntOpt('max_worker', default='10', help='max worker of service'),
    cfg.IntOpt('qos_worker', default='50', help='Max message can consumer by worker in concurrently'),
    cfg.StrOpt('queue_name', default='CTL_MJPEG', help='Listening queue name')
]

keep_alive_group = cfg.OptGroup(name='keepaliveworker', title='Configuration of keep alive worker')

keep_alive_opts = [
    cfg.IntOpt('max_worker', default='10', help='max worker of keep alive service'),
    cfg.IntOpt('qos_worker', default='50', help='Max message can consumer by worker in concurrently'),
    cfg.StrOpt('queue_name', default='CTL_MJPEG_RECOVERY', help='listening queue name')
]

monitor_queue_group = cfg.OptGroup(name='queuemonitor', title='Configuration of queue monitor')

monitor_queue_opts = [
    cfg.IntOpt('max_worker', default='1', help='max worker of keep alive service'),
    cfg.StrOpt('queue_name', default='MONITOR_QUEUE', help='Queue name using receiver event'),
    cfg.IntOpt('qos_worker', default='50', help='Max message can consumer by worker in concurrently'),
    cfg.StrOpt('monitor_topic', default='queue.*',
               help='Monitor queue when queue have been deleted(recovery function)'),
]


log_group = cfg.OptGroup(name='logcfg', title='Log Configuration of queue monitor')

log_opts = [
    cfg.StrOpt('log_cfg_dir', default='/etc/cloudmjpeg/log.conf.d', help='Directory save log config'),
    cfg.StrOpt('monitor_log', help='log configuration for monitor server'),
    cfg.StrOpt('worker_log', help='log configuration for monitor server'),
    cfg.StrOpt('queue_monitor_log', help='log configuration for queue monitor server'),
    cfg.StrOpt('keep_alive_log', help='log configuration for monitor server'),
]

portal_group = cfg.OptGroup(name='portal', title='Configuration about interact with portal')

portal_opts = [
    cfg.BoolOpt('send_file_info', default=False, help='Enable send file info to portal'),
]

alarming_group = cfg.OptGroup(name='alarming', title='Configuration about alarming to portal to send mail to customer')

alarming_opts = [
    cfg.BoolOpt('file_size', default=False, help='Enable alarming for file size'),
    cfg.BoolOpt('camera_status_change', default=False, help='Enable alarming when status of camera change')
]

monitor_group = cfg.OptGroup(name='monitor', title='Configuration using keep alive data')

monitor_opts = [
    cfg.IntOpt('check_interval', default=60, help='Interval check data'),
    cfg.StrOpt('email_subject', default='Keep Alive Monitor', help='Subject of Email send to admin'),
    cfg.IntOpt('check_alive', default=60, help='If start and end time have interval is check alive, then worker died')
]

ffserver_group = cfg.OptGroup(name='ffserver', title='Configuration for ffserver')

ffserver_opts = [
    cfg.IntOpt(name='ffm_file_size', default=500, help='Size of ffm temp. Unit kilo bytes'),
    cfg.StrOpt(name='ffm_dir', default='/tmp/ffmpeg-temp/', help='FFm temp file location'),
]



def parser(conf):
    CONF = cfg.CONF

    CONF.register_group(rabbitmq_opt_group)
    CONF.register_opts(rabbitmq_opts, rabbitmq_opt_group)

    CONF.register_group(worker_opt_group)
    CONF.register_opts(worker_opts, worker_opt_group)

    CONF.register_group(keep_alive_group)
    CONF.register_opts(keep_alive_opts, keep_alive_group)

    CONF.register_group(monitor_queue_group)
    CONF.register_opts(monitor_queue_opts, monitor_queue_group)

    CONF.register_group(log_group)
    CONF.register_opts(log_opts, log_group)

    CONF.register_group(portal_group)
    CONF.register_opts(portal_opts, portal_group)

    CONF.register_group(alarming_group)
    CONF.register_opts(alarming_opts, alarming_group)

    CONF.register_group(monitor_group)
    CONF.register_opts(monitor_opts, monitor_group)

    CONF.register_group(ffserver_group)
    CONF.register_opts(ffserver_opts, ffserver_group)


    CONF(default_config_files=conf)
    return CONF

def get_configuration():
    CONF = parser(['/etc/cloudmjpeg/cloudmjpeg.conf'])
    return CONF
```

I add my configuration to settings.py. It will load my configuration from /etc/cloudmjpeg/cloudmjpeg.conf.

```
from cloudmjpeg.utils import configloader
MJPEG_CONF = configloader.get_configuration()
```

Howerver I remove load my configruration into settings.py. It will run app using python manage.py command line perfect. So that I think when I load my configuration in settings.py, it will be error. Why?. I do not any idea to resolve problem. Please help me.
Thanks